# The hibernate.properties file doesn't change the hibernate dialect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have created a [spring](https://spring.io/) application with MySql db connected and I want the hibernate to create tables using Innodb engine but it always creates the table using MyISAM engine.
the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

The `hibernate.properties` file:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
```

The console output:

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

2017-12-18 13:54:19.460  INFO 9144 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on webc13 with PID 9144 (C:\spring\gs-rest-service\complete\build\classes\main started by Arielb in C:\spring\gs-rest-service\complete)
2017-12-18 13:54:19.465  INFO 9144 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-18 13:54:19.506  INFO 9144 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@44a3ec6b: startup date [Mon Dec 18 13:54:19 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-18 13:54:20.802  WARN 9144 --- [           main] o.h.v.m.ParameterMessageInterpolator     : HV000184: ParameterMessageInterpolator has been chosen, EL interpolation will not be supported
2017-12-18 13:54:21.102  WARN 9144 --- [           main] o.h.v.m.ParameterMessageInterpolator     : HV000184: ParameterMessageInterpolator has been chosen, EL interpolation will not be supported
2017-12-18 13:54:21.371  INFO 9144 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-18 13:54:21.380  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-12-18 13:54:21.381  INFO 9144 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2017-12-18 13:54:21.517  INFO 9144 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-12-18 13:54:21.518  INFO 9144 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2014 ms
2017-12-18 13:54:21.634  INFO 9144 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-12-18 13:54:21.638  INFO 9144 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-18 13:54:21.639  INFO 9144 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-18 13:54:21.639  INFO 9144 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-18 13:54:21.639  INFO 9144 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-18 13:54:22.051  INFO 9144 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-18 13:54:22.060  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-12-18 13:54:22.114  INFO 9144 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-12-18 13:54:22.116  INFO 9144 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect, spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=myisam}
2017-12-18 13:54:22.117  INFO 9144 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-12-18 13:54:22.151  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-12-18 13:54:22.236  INFO 9144 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-12-18 13:54:22.527  INFO 9144 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2017-12-18 13:54:22.555  INFO 9144 --- [           main] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: logs
2017-12-18 13:54:22.555  INFO 9144 --- [           main] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: logs
2017-12-18 13:54:22.741  INFO 9144 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-18 13:54:23.178  INFO 9144 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@44a3ec6b: startup date [Mon Dec 18 13:54:19 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-18 13:54:23.231  INFO 9144 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/dd/one/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public hello.Files hello.controller.InspectorController.getFile(java.lang.Integer)
2017-12-18 13:54:23.232  INFO 9144 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/dd/all],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Iterable<hello.Files> hello.controller.InspectorController.getAllUsers()
2017-12-18 13:54:23.232  INFO 9144 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/dd/insert],methods=[POST]}" onto public hello.Files hello.controller.InspectorController.saveFiles(java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws javassist.tools.web.BadHttpRequest
2017-12-18 13:54:23.232  INFO 9144 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/greeting]}" onto public hello.Greeting hello.GreetingController.greeting(java.lang.String)
2017-12-18 13:54:23.234  INFO 9144 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-12-18 13:54:23.234  INFO 9144 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-12-18 13:54:23.259  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-18 13:54:23.259  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-18 13:54:23.287  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-18 13:54:23.459  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-12-18 13:54:23.504  INFO 9144 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-18 13:54:23.508  INFO 9144 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 4.291 seconds (JVM running for 4.77)
```

Any idea?

### Edit

finally, the only way I managed to reach the desired engine was to set the `my.conf` file:

```
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

Comment: could be `hibernate.properties` is not visible somehow (e.g. not on classpath)

Comment: Don't use `hibernate.properties` instead put those in `application.properties`. Instead of `hibernate.dialect` use `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`.

Comment: It throws a BeanCreationException.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Add the exception stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [post](http://in.relation.to/2017/02/20/mysql-dialect-refactoring/), the `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` has been deprecated, the class to use is `MySQL5Dialect`.

So you need to change the dialect :

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
```

If it doesn't work, try using the spring jpa properties :
 `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`

Comment: Did you use the spring jpa properties ?

Comment: Yes, see above, the `application.properties` file

Answer (score 1):

change your  `hibernate.properties` file to

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
```

and then try it.  `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` is deprecated .

Answer (score 0):

`spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect` work for me, but MySQL57InnoDBDialect was marked as deprecated.

It suggested that using `hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb` but it is not working for me.

So I keep `MySQL57InnoDBDialect`.